# How can I get selected value in select dom element [Laravel]

Tags: php, laravel

Can someone tell me how can I get selected value when I try to edit post in Laravel project.
*So here are parts of code*

**Post.php:**

```
public function category(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}
```

**Category.php:**

```
public function posts(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}
```

**PostController.php:**

```
 $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
 $categories = Category::all();
 $tags = Tag::all();
 return view('admin.posts.edit', ['post' => $post, 'categories' => $categories, 'tags' => $tags]);
```

**posts/edit.blade.php:**

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="category_id">Selecet category</label>
        <select name="category_id" id="category_id" class="form-control">
            <option disabled>List of available post categories</option>
            @foreach($categories as $category)

                <option value="{{ $category->id }}" {{$category->id == $category->id ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $category->name }}</option>

            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: $category->id == $category->id. This is always true.

Comment: ty problem alrdy solved :D u can check my answer at the bottom (if you could just accept it because it may help others in future) btw ty for your answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved with this part of code (for future users who will read this :) )

```
@foreach($categories as $category)

    <option value="{{ $category->id }}"

        @if($post->category->id == $category->id)

           selected

        @endif

    >{{ $category->name }}</option>

@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @Hardood mentioned. `$category->id == $category->id` will always return true. In fact, if you just want to get the value from form submission. You can just remove that. HTML will handle selected value itself.

You can simply use `$request->category_name` in your backend.

Comment: ty problem alrdy solved :D u can check my answer at the bottom (if you could just accept it because it may help others in future) btw ty for your answer :)